# Inserting single quote in JDBC for SQL Query not working

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, special-characters

I'm having issues dealing with the single quote while using it in a prepared statement in JAVA via Oracle JDBC.

Let's say we have a table Restaurant with a column restaurant_name with 1 value : Jack's Deli

I want to use a simple prepared statement query like this:

```
    String result = "Jack\'\'s Deli"
    String sqlStatement = "select * from Restaurant where restauraunt_name like ? escape '\\' ";
    PreparedStatement pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);
    pstmt.setString(1, result);
```

The result shows 0 returned values, however when I directly search the query in the database (ORACLE) it works fine and retrieves the result. (Oracle uses two single quotes as an escape for the first)

I am thinking that the value is not being passed properly to the database. Or there is some other formatting issue.

Comment: Why do you think you need to escape the `'` in the `result` value? You are setting it as a parameter value on a prepared statement, so no quoting is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The point of prepared statements is that you don't need any escaping.

`.setString(1, "Jack's Deli")` will get it done.